# Propagate new Observable's value to some observers only

Tags: rxjs

Suppose we have an `Observable` which is subscribed to by multiple observers.

When that `Observable` emits a new value, can we control which of its observers would get the new value?

I'm attempting to implement a scenario when observers are receiving the new value one by one and expected to return `true` or `false` in response to that value. When a first observer returns `true`, the rest of observers must not receive the new value.

Comment: Yo have several observers for the same observable, the first one (must be defined) who recieve the first value continue to listen but the others die ? Is this what you want ?

Comment: @bubbles Yes, except the 'die' part. All observers must stay subscribed. The only behavior compared to the standard 'subject.next(newValue)' I'm attempting to change is that the list pf observers must be iterated (and the current one must be provided with the `newValue`) until the current subscriber returns `true`. At this point the iteration must be stopped meaning other subscribers won't receive this `newValue`. However, during the next `next()`, the whole process must be possible again.

Comment: Can you add some code ? i cannot get you. I’m sorry

Comment: @bubbles I'm not sure how to show it in the code. **1. You have 10 observers.** If you do `next(...)`, all 10 of them get iterated and are provided with the new value. that's how RxJS works by default. What I'd like to do is like the following. **2. Take the first (or next in the list) observer, provide it with the new value. 3. If it responds 'That value is for me! Do not pass the value to any other observers!'- stop iterating observers immediately. 4. If the current observer responded 'No, it's not for me!' - go to the second (next) observer and repeat steps #2-#4 for the rest of observers**

Comment: Ah it seems like you have a descriminator in your value to know if it is for the right observer ? If so `filterˋ can do it, no ?

Comment: You could extend the `Subject` class and override the `next()` method with your custom code to check for a return value from each individual observer's `next()` method, breaking out of the loop if any return value is `true`.  Source code [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.5.2/src/internal/Subject.ts#L18-L147), look at `AsyncSubject` for an example of how to extend the `Subject` class.

Comment: Why do you want to control the data flow from your Observable? I don't think Observables and Observers are supposed to communicate with each other in that way. If an Observer receives a value it's not interested in (case: No, it's not for me!) the standard approach would be to make it use a [`filter`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/filter) to filter out values it shouldn't act uppon.